# Using Apache POI XSSFWorkbook, how can I refresh all formula cells at once?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Please have a look on this issue :

I'm loading a large `.xlsx` file with size say 5MB & having about 30 sheets using `Apache POI` & putting values to some cells. But after writing all data to a sheet, the workbook don't get refreshed, means formula on different cells don't get evaluated.

I used "`XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);`", it's giving some errors like this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown error type:
 -60 at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaError.forInt(FormulaError.java:131)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellErrorValue(XSSFCell.java:667) 

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.setCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:209) 

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:153) 

at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:327) 

at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:318) 

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:238) at com.RefreshExcelFile.main(RefreshExcelFile.java:15)
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Looks like one of your formulas is problematic. Can you try evaluating each cell in turn, and work out from that what the problem formula is?

Answer (score 1):

You have to follows these steps

`XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
workbook.write();`

But your problem looks like with the definition formula